# API to get Azure object-id from application-id

Tags: azure

I have an application which is registered in Azure (followed this [guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/python/sdk/authentication-on-premises-apps?source=recommendations&tabs=azure-portal)). I have the application-id for this application, and I would like to find its object-id by using Azure API (I am using python library). How can I retrieve the object-id?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that [msgraph-core](https://pypi.org/project/msgraph-core/) (in preview) can be used for this purpose.

Sample code:

```
def get_object_id(self, app_id, tenant_id, client_id, client_secret):
    credential = ClientSecretCredential(tenant_id, client_id, client_secret)        
    client = GraphClient(credential=credential)
    endpoint = "/servicePrincipals"
    select = "displayName,id,appId"
    req_filter = f"appId eq '{app_id}'"
    request_url = f'{endpoint}?$select={select}&$filter={req_filter}'

    response = client.get(request_url)
    return response.json()['value'][0]['id']
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need the object id for the service principal, you can use the service principal list endpoint with a filter. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/serviceprincipal-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

Example filter: `$filter=appId eq 'your-app-id'`

Comment: Thanks. Is there a python API for it?